# How to upvote an editor?

Tags: discussion, support, editing, up-votes

Say I see this question

1. initially made by a newcomer which is full of lack of typesetting and other things you can expect.
2. really well edited by some seasoned guy

Is there some way to "upvote" the editor for their work? I mean after you reach some threshold you don't get points for accepted edits any longer.

If there is no way to do this, should there be a way to do it?

Comment: You tagged this feature request but your post does not directly propose a feature but rather asks if or how this could be done. This is a bit confusing. For the question as is support might be more appropriate. Likely, you also want to discuss the pros and cons a bit, so add discussion too, and mention this in the question. If you actually just want to propose this feature than it would be better to do so directly.

Comment: @quid: yes it is so seldom I post on meta so I forgot the suitable tags. Feel free to edit if you want to. It is sometimes a feature I am missing, but I would first ask if it exists rather than to add it ( in case it already exists but I'm just unaware of how to do it ).

Comment: I made the changes I proposed. Obviosuly, If you do not like them, feel free to revert.

Comment: I actually think this is a good idea. I would like to see a system by which you can up vote an edit done by someone, thus giving them $1$ reputation - not enough to diminish the value of reputation; but you still get that green feel good notification. I think it particularly applies when someone converts a newcomer's post of verbal diarrhea into nicely formatted latex - an up vote would be a nice way to give recognition where its due.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way to upvote an editor of a post in a way that would give them points or anything like that. It is also better not to think of upvoting as upvoting the user that wrote the post, but rather as upvoting the post. Thus, if you like the post now, upvote the post.

I'd rather advise against upvoting an other post of the editor or things like that.

What you can do is write a comment addressed at the editor that positively acknowledges their work. It is better not do this systematically but in exceptional cases I think it is fine:

> @{editing user's name}: thank you for clarifying this post, I saw its original version and did not understand it. Now, it is very clear and interesting.

Note that one can actually comment-notify editors, even though auto-complete does not propose them.

Since you tagged this feature request let me add that I do not think such a feature is needed or desirable. I feel there is some value in edits being just altruistic as far as points go.